# How to display a dropdown menu using nested json list angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, dropdown

This is my list in the controller:

```
vm.areaList.push({"areaId":"101","areaName":"A","subAreaNames":["AA","BB"
                     ,"CC","DD","EE","FF","GG","HH"]});
vm.areaList.push({"areaId":"102","areaName":"B","subAreaNames":["II","JJ" ]});
        vm.areaList.push({"areaId":"103","areaName":"Administration","subAreaNames":["KK","LL","MM"]});
```

And this is the first dropdown on my html page:

```
<select multiple="multiple" data-ng-options="area.areaId as area.areaName for area in AreaReportCtrl.areaList" 
             data-ng-model="AreaReportCtrl.selectedArea">
            </select>
```

Based on the value selected from this dropdown I want to populate another dropdown with the corresponding sub-areas list.

Is it possible to keep the area and sub area data in single array ? If yes, how shall I iterate it in ng-options of the next dropdown based on the selected area? Or should I store the sub-area list in a different array by keeping a reference of the areaId ?

Comment: You can create a new sub area list based on `areaId` or when you change the area call a method and initialise the sub areas to another variable and the itterate with the newly assigned value

Comment: I was looking for a solution to iterate the same list in the second dropdown also if possible and was trying to avoid calling a method on selection if that is possible

Comment: how are you expecting this to work with `select multiple`?  are you wanting to aggregate all the possible sub-areas?

Comment: @Claies, user can select multiple areas and all the corresponding sub areas should be displayed in another list

Comment: so then that's a yes, you want to aggregate the sub-areas?  that won't be possible without firing some function.

Comment: @Claies, Ok thanks for clarification

Answer (score 1):

```
<select data-ng-options="area.areaId as area.areaName for area in AreaReportCtrl.areaList" 
             data-ng-model="AreaReportCtrl.selectedArea">
            </select>

<select data-ng-options="subAreaName as subAreaName  for area.subAreaNames in AreaReportCtrl.areaList|filter:{areaId:AreaReportCtrl.selectedArea}" 
             data-ng-model="AreaReportCtrl.selectedArea">
            </select>
```

Comment: this won't work with `select multiple`, since `selectedArea` will be an array.

Comment: you need multiple means you need to fire an event

Comment: Ok got it. When I try your code for single selection, I get this error: [ngOptions:iexp] Expected expression in form of '_select_ (as _label_)? for (_key_,)?_value_ in _collection_' but got 'subareaName as subareaName for area.subareaNames in AreaReportCtrl.areaList|filter:{areaId:AreaReportCtrl.selectedArea}'